# Viusal studio python error when using requests package (error : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0))

Tags: python, python-requests

Im getting the error whenever i try to run this code in visual studio code.

**Image of code**

[image]

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\climia1\Downloads\hangman.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=29d9ecf6-71bb-49b1-b931-e0ed5f00f31d').json()
  File "C:\Users\climia1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\climia1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\climia1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\climia1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 18.946 seconds
```

it displays the same error on repl.it but it goes away after one run. with visual studio it stays. any help?

Comment: Check if the response code is 200

Answer (score 0):

Your json file must be empty or isn't formatted properly

if you are reading or writing to a empty Json file make sure it contains `{}`

if you are writing or reading a json file with lot of data make sure all the tags are closed